# Wrong x-axis with pst-plot

Tags: pstricks, labels, pst-plot

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-coil,pst-plot}

\def\tilskud#1#2{%
 \psline[linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red]%
  (!#1 1986   sub 0)%
  (!#1 1986   sub #2 8 sub 2 div)%
  (!#1 1986.2 sub #2 8 sub 2 div)%
  (!#1 1985.8 sub #2 8 sub 2 div)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.35,-0.4)(9.15,7.7)
\psaxes[
  yAxis=false,
  xLabels={,1987,,1989,,1991,1992,1992,1994}
]{->}(0,0)(0,0)(8.5,0)[Fish,0][,90]
\psyTick(0){0}
\psaxes[xAxis=false](0,0)(0,0.2)
\pszigzag[coilarm=0.0625,coilwidth=0.3,coilheight=0.5](0,0.2)(0,0.8)
\psaxes[
  xAxis=false,
  Oy=10,
  dy=0.5,
  ylabelFactor={\cdot 10^6}
]{->}(0,1)(0,0.75)(0,7.35)[,0][Horse,90]
\multido{\r=1+0.5}{13}{\psline[linestyle=dotted](0,\r)(8.5,\r)}
\tilskud{1987}{14.28}
\tilskud{1989}{15.548}
\tilskud{1991}{21.4}
\tilskud{1992}{20.24}
\tilskud{1993}{17.64}
\tilskud{1994}{14.442}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I would like to have the labels as I have tried to define them using `xLabels`; how do I get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
xLabels={,1987, ,1989, ,1991,1992,1992,1994}
```

It needs a space if there should be no value

Comment: Great! Is this something introduced in the latest version? I can't remember ever having to do this (but I might be wrong, of course).

Comment: maybe. I have no time to investigate.

Comment: Okay. If you would please comment on it when you have time, it would be nice. (I might have to change it in some other documents too to make them compilable.)

Comment: use `http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-plot/` or wait for the next TL update